# Dual Monitor Won't work with DVI and VGA Together

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have a replicator port (VGA only) that goes with my Dell Laptop. I also have one Dell monitor (VGA) and a second Dell monitor with both VGA and DVI.  The replicator port only has one VGA port.  I can create a dual screen using the laptop screen and either monitor, but when I try to go dual monitors (laptop screen closed), nothing shows up on the VGA monitor. Is it possible to use both types of monitors?

Comment: Most laptop graphics cards will ONLY give the laptop screen + one extra screen - regardless of whether you have a replicator. It is a limitation of the graphics cards used. Many new laptops have DisplayPort ports which CAN achieve true dual (or even triple) screens plus the laptop built-in display.

Comment: You did not specify what model you are using for:

1) Dell laptop
2) Replicator
3) VGA Monitor
4) VGA+DVI Monitor

Comment: If the graphics card cannot drive the monitors you need, you may consider an USB-graphics adapter for each extra monitor.  Note that they are slower so games and movies will not do well, but for office work it may be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics it is hard to say.

From my personal experience, I have a [Dell E6420](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/latitude-e6420/pd) with a [replicator dock](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=430-3114) that has 1 VGA and 2 DVI ports.

[image: Dell replicator dock]

My dual monitor at home is connected to the replicator dock. First is VGA cable and second is via DVI cable with the laptop screen closed. The home set up is tricky as it involves the replicator connecting to the VGA port and one of the DVI ports. If both your monitors are DVI, the process is much easier.

**Two options:**

1. Try different cable combinations. VGA has only one possibility, but DVI could be placed into port 1 or 2. In between combinations, make sure to fully close the laptop screen and shut down the laptop each time you try a different combination.
2. Replace the VGA monitor with one that supports DVI.

**Why you can not use a VGA to DVI cable.**

You can not use VGA to DVI cable converter since the replicator dock only accepts DVI-D (DVI digital).

[image: dock]

[image: dvi-connector]
source: [datapro](http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/dvi_info.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to use both the VGA and DVI ports in a port replicator, the laptop must have for the Intel graphics chipset, and either AMD or Nvidia graphics chipset as well.  The VGA port will utilize the Intel chipset, and the DVI ports will utilize the other graphics chipset.  We have many machines where I work that we have set up using this configuration for the Dell D and E series latitude laptops and the Precision workstation series laptops using the D series, E series, or newer USB C style port replicators(based on the requirement of the machine).  Good luck!